# Spring Crud Repository - Unsatisfied dependency expressed - Cant inject model

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, project-structure, spring-repositories

i seem to be unable to get Spring to recognize the native `CrudRepository` and use it, because spring isn not able to inject / use the actual class that my generic `CrudRepository` needs to implement *when i put it in a different package than the one with the main method.*

My Project structure is pretty straight forward.

[image]

**Leaving the structure like this works just fine!**

I want however `Author` to be inside the `model` package, like this:

[image]

However Spring always throws the error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'demoApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authorRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorRepository' defined in service.AuthorRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DemoApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class model.Author
```

**I definately dont want to use a configuration through an application.properties.xml file. I want it to be programmatically configured within java code.**

The `Author.java` :

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

The `AuthorRepository` that implements the `CrudRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Integer> {
}
```

If it is of any importance here is the `Config` class where i define my `DataSource`. The `@Bean` with `Author` seems not important, since it works without it too when i leave the `Author` inside the `com.example.demo` package.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sks");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("sks");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("technikum1");

        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Author author(){
        return new Author();
    }
}
```

And finally my Main method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"config"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"service"})
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Iterable<Author> authors = authorRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println(authors);
    }
}
```

I tried annotating the `AuthorRepository` with a `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"model"})` and annotated the `Author.java` with `@Component` because i thought it might not recognize it as bean or something if i put it in another package ( which would be strange anyway since i dont need the component annotation when i leave it in the main package) but nothing worked so far.
Generally struggling hard with project structure and Spring....

Also i have tried to change the  `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"config"})` in `DemoApplication` to `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"config","model"})`.

Nothing worked so far !

I need some help ...

Comment: Try to put the `config`, `model` and `service` packages inside the `com.example.demo` one

Comment: Place DemoApplication class in java package (root package for services, repositories)

Comment: I dont want to do a workaround... i basicly just want to know how i do exactly this. What is the logic behind the discovery ? It must be possible to just put models inside the model package... :/ I know that it works when i move all the packages inside the root package. But thanks anyway for your help guys !!

Comment: also try this `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "service",...})`

Comment: You need `@EntityScan` also. Or just put everything in a proper structure and that way you only need `@SpringBootApplication` and it will figure all of that out itself.

Comment: Entity Scan was what i am looking for... thanks a lot ! Why is the structure not proper in your opinion ? Because the packages are not subpackages of the main package ?